# I'm having issue with the output with this particular code

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

**This is the code:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class javapractice {
        public static void main(String[] Args) {
            int XX = 0;
            int count = 0;
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    
            while (true) {
                System.out.println("Enter Number :");
                int number = input.nextInt();
                boolean nextint = input.hasNextInt();
                if (nextint) {
                    count++;
                    XX += number;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
                input.nextLine();
            }
           int YY = XX/count;
            System.out.println("SUM = " + XX + " AVG = " + YY);
            input.close();
        }
    }
```

I want the output to print the sum of the numbers entered and when I enter let's say a word like "Hello", it breaks out of the loop and prints `Sum 0 0` and `AVG = 0`.

The issue I'm having is that whenever I enter the number, it asks me for it two times and doesn't take the next number in the row after that and whenever I enter a string variable lets say "I", it outputs Inputmismatch. What would be the fix to this?

Comment: I don't know the answer just by looking at the code, but my immediate advice is, don't ignore the return value of `input.nextLine()`.  That may be reading portions of the input you don't expect it to.

Comment: Java coding conventions have variables and methods starting with a lower-case letter (xx); classes start with an upper-case letter (JavaPractice).

Comment: Gotcha, will take care of that.

Answer (score 1):

Don't mix `nextLine()` and all the other `next` methods; pick one. If you want to read a line's worth of text, just call `next()`, but if you want the input to flow as 'everytime a user hits enter, read another token', which you usually do, update the definition of 'what defines a token?': `scanner.useDelimiter("\r?\n");`.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this code:**

```
    int XX = 0;
    int count = 0;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Enter Number: ");
        if (input.hasNextInt()) {
            count++;
            XX += input.nextInt();
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    int YY = XX / count;
    System.out.println("SUM = " + XX + " AVG = " + YY);
    input.close();
```